# Can someone give me detailed technical reasons why writing to a secondary in MongoDB replica set is not allowed

Tags: mongodb, performance, replication, database, nosql

I know we can't write to a secondary in MongoDB. But I can't find any technical reason why. In my case, I don't really care if there is a slight delay but write to a secondary might be faster. Please provide some reference if you can. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you can not write to a secondary is the way replication works:

Secondaries connect to a special collection on the primary, called `oplog`. This `oplog` contains operations which were run through the query optimizer. Basically, the oplog is a capped collection, and the secondaries use a tailable cursor to access it's entries and processes it from the oldest to the newest.

When a election takes place because the primary goes down / steps down, the secondary with the most recent oplog entry is elected primary. The secondaries connect to the new primary, query for the oplog entries they haven't processed yet and the cluster is in sync.

This procedure is pretty straight forward. Now imagine one could write to a secondary. All nodes in the cluster would have to have a tailable cursor on all other nodes of the cluster, and maintaining a consistent state in case of one machine failing becomes a *very* complicated and in case of a failure even race condition dependent thing. Effectively, there could be no guarantee even for eventual consistency any more. It would be a more or less a gamble.

That being said: A replica set is *not* for load balancing. A replica sets purpose is to enhance the *availability and durability* of the data. Because reading from a secondary is a non-risky thing, MongoDB made it possible, according to their dogma of offering the maximum of possible features without compromising scalability (which would be severely hampered if one could write to secondaries).

But MongoDB *does* provide a load balancing feature: [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/). Choosing the right shard key, you can distribute read and write load over (almost) as many shards as you want. Not to mention that you can provide a lot more of the precious RAM for a reasonable price when sharding.

Comment: @ Markus-W-Mahlbergand Sammaye have good knowledge about replica-set and journalling, both voted-up

Answer (score 3):

There is a one liner answer:

Multi-master replication is a hairball.

If you was allowed to write to secondaries MongoDB would have to use milti-master replication to ge this working: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-master_replication where essentially evey node copies to each other the OPs (operations) they have received and somehow do it without losing data.

This form of replication has many obsticles to overcome.

One would be throughput; remember that OPs need to transfer across the entire network so it is possible you might actually lose throughput while adding consistentcy problems. So getting better throughput would be a problem. It is much having a secondary, taking all of the primaries OPs and then its own for replication outbound and then asking it to do yet another job.

Adding consistentcy over a distributed set like this would also be hazardous, one main question that bugs MongoDB when asking if a member is down or is: "Is it really down or just unavailable?". It is almost impossible to ensure true consistentcy in a distributed set like this, at the very least tricky.

Those are just two problems immediately.

Essentially, to sum up, MongoDB does not yet possess mlti-master replication. It could in the future but I would not be jumping for joy if it does, I will most likely ignore such a feature, normal replication and sharding in both ACID and non-ACID databases causes enough blood pressure.

Comment: Was just about to edit my post about concurrent write operations on the same document, which you implicitly covered, too.